# Unable to display data on datatable

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, json

I making a 3rd party callout and receiving a data in the format given below:

```
arr= [{
                "Name": "Bazargate",
                "Description": null,
                "BranchType": "Sub Post Office",
                "DeliveryStatus": "Non-Delivery",
                "Circle": "Maharashtra",
                "District": "Mumbai",
                "Division": "Mumbai  South",
                "Region": "Mumbai",
                "Block": "Mumbai",
                "State": "Maharashtra",
                "Country": "India",
                "Pincode": "400001"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Elephanta Caves Po",
                "Description": null,
                "BranchType": "Branch Office directly a/w Head Office",
                "DeliveryStatus": "Delivery",
                "Circle": "Maharashtra",
                "District": "Raigarh(MH)",
                "Division": "Mumbai  South",
                "Region": "Mumbai",
                "Block": "Uran",
                "State": "Maharashtra",
                "Country": "India",
                "Pincode": "400001"
            }]
```

The problem is I am unable to display the data on the lightning-datatable

HTML:

```
<template>
<lightning-card title="List of Post Office">
    <lightning-input class="slds-m-around_medium" type="number" label="Enter the pin code"
        onchange={pinCodeHandler}>
    </lightning-input>
    <lightning-button class="slds-m-around_medium" label="View available post offices" variant="brand"
        onclick={viewPostOffice}></lightning-button>
    <lightning-datatable key-field="Name" data={result} columns={columns}>
    </lightning-datatable>
</lightning-card>
```

JS:

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';
import getPostOffice from '@salesforce/apex/IndianPostal.fetchPostOfficeByPin';

const columns = [
    { label: 'Branch Type', fieldName: 'BranchType' },
    { label: 'Circle', fieldName: 'Circle' },
    { label: 'Country', fieldName: 'Country'},
    { label: 'Delivery Status', fieldName: 'DeliveryStatus' },
    { label: 'District', fieldName: 'District' },
    { label: 'Division', fieldName: 'Division' },
    { label: 'Name', fieldName: 'Name'},
    { label: 'Region', fieldName: 'Region' },
    { label: 'State', fieldName: 'State' },
];

export default class PostOfficeLocator extends LightningElement {
    pincode;
    result;
    // @track data=[]; 

    pinCodeHandler(event){
        this.pincode = event.target.value;
    }
    
    viewPostOffice(){
        getPostOffice({pincode : this.pincode}).then(response => {
            this.result = response;
            console.log('**********RESPONSE*******', response);
        }).catch(error=>{
            console.log('**********ERROR**********', error.body.message);
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define column and response variable inside js as a variable. Try out the below code.

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';
import getPostOffice from '@salesforce/apex/IndianPostal.fetchPostOfficeByPin';

 const columns = [
{ label: 'Branch Type', fieldName: 'BranchType' },
{ label: 'Circle', fieldName: 'Circle' },
{ label: 'Country', fieldName: 'Country'},
{ label: 'Delivery Status', fieldName: 'DeliveryStatus' },
{ label: 'District', fieldName: 'District' },
{ label: 'Division', fieldName: 'Division' },
{ label: 'Name', fieldName: 'Name'},
{ label: 'Region', fieldName: 'Region' },
{ label: 'State', fieldName: 'State' },
 ];

 export default class PostOfficeLocator extends LightningElement {
pincode;
columns = columns;
response;
// @track data=[]; 

pinCodeHandler(event){
    this.pincode = event.target.value;
}

viewPostOffice(){
    getPostOffice({pincode : this.pincode}).then(response => {
        this.response = respose;
        console.log('**********RESPONSE*******', response);
    }).catch(error=>{
        console.log('**********ERROR**********', error.body.message);
    })
}
```

}

Comment: I did that still the data is not displayed

Comment: Can you show the updated code?

Comment: updated the code

Comment: columns = columns; this is missing

Comment: thanks for the help